# Как задать таску с небольшим отличием для каждого сервера

Tags: ansible

У меня есть есть список хостов:

```
192.168.77.101 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
192.168.77.102 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
192.168.77.103 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
```

Для каждого из них мне необходимо выполнить команду:

```
echo "1" > /data/zookeeper/myid
```

Но число после `echo` у каждого сервера будет свое (от 1 до 3). Есть ли простой способ сделать это?

Answer (score 2):

Например, можно так:

```
192.168.77.101 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant echo=1
192.168.77.102 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant echo=2
192.168.77.103 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant echo=3
...
tasks:
- name: set
  copy:
    content: "{{ echo }}"
    dest: /data/zookeeper/myid
```